# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Hotel_Manager/HotelsMangerUser.dat (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, ioexception

In my activity when the user login 
I check if the file with the user list exists , in case the method returns false , I create a new file where to save this list.

This is the method:

```
public boolean isLoginFilePresent() {
        file = new File(loginData.getPath());//file name /sdcard/Hotel_Manager/HotelsMangerUser.dat;

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        present = file.exists();
        return present;
    }
```

But I get the following error ( this is the log ):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Hotel_Manager/HotelsMangerUser.dat (No such file or directory)
08-13 11:15:36.174 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at app.com.hotelsmanager.Controller.LoginDataSaver.saveLoginData(LoginDataSaver.java:108)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at app.com.hotelsmanager.Controller.LoginController.addDemoLoginFile(LoginController.java:130)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at app.com.hotelsmanager.View.Activities.LoginViewActivity.loginMe(LoginViewActivity.java:101)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at app.com.hotelsmanager.View.Activities.LoginViewActivity.-wrap0(LoginViewActivity.java)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at app.com.hotelsmanager.View.Activities.LoginViewActivity$1.onClick(LoginViewActivity.java:71)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
08-13 11:15:36.175 12174-12174/app.com.hotelsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What I wrong?

Thanks for helping me!!!!

Comment: Make sure your file or folder path exists.

Comment: `isLoginFilePresent()` will ALWAYS return true. Well if the file is created. But you create a new  empty  file ALWAYS with `file.createNewFile()`.

Comment: But as the problem arises with `FileOutputStream` you should show that code.

Comment: `in case the method returns false , I create a new file where to save this list.`. You are not showing that code. Moreover do you check there if the file exists?

Answer (score 1):

This is the method for save user into file

```
public void saveLoginData(Set<User> accountSet, Context context) {
        final List<String> loginFile = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final User u : accountSet) {
            loginFile.add(u.getName() + Constants.USERDATA_SEPARATOR + u.getPassword() +
                    Constants.USERDATA_SEPARATOR + u.getAccessLevel().toString());
        }
        try {
            sdDir = new File(Constants.USER_DIR); //USER_DIR = "/sdcard/Hotel_Manger"
            sdDir.mkdirs();
            userOutput = new File(sdDir,Constants.USER_PATH);//USER_PATH = "HotelManagerUser.dat"
            fos = new FileOutputStream(userOutput);   //<------this return FileNotFoundException e
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(loginFile);
            out.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```